# C++ Cannot open output file:permission denied

Tags: c++

I have been searching for the solution to this problem for a bit now. It seems that the program is still running even after I stop it in eclipse. I have to go to task manager to end the process to get it to stop. This is for a homework assignment involving finding the logical error. I don't want my homework done for me but I have no idea of what is going on. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 int i=0;

 int x;

 int y;

 int temp;

 int array[10];

 //Enter new data in to array
 for (i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
      printf("\n enter new number = ");
      scanf("%d", &array[i]);
 }

 //Print the new data
 for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      printf("%d ",array[i]);

 //Find the largest number in the array
 for(x = 0; x < 10 ; x++)
      for(y = 0; y < 9; y++)
           if(array[y] > array[y+1])
           {
               temp = array[y+1];

               array[y+1] = array[y];

               array[y] = temp;
           }
  printf(" largest = %d \n", temp);

   for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i]);

   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you deduct that the program is still running, even after you close the dialog box (if any)?

Comment: May be its on the file permission of the file you're reading. Change it using <code>chmod</code> in terminal if you're using Mac, or <code>attrib</code> if you're using Windows.

Comment: where does the code stop? is there any output currently in the console window before it becomes unresponsive??